# What are some good rpgs to start with after D&D?

Tags: game-recommendation

I'm looking for a few rpgs to start playing with my friends. We've been playing D&D for a long time but I know that this isn't the only one out there. Any ideas? If there are any DC comics superhero type rpgs, I would love that. Other than that, I'll try anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get a chance. Unfortunately, after a great deal of discussion the community here decided not to allow game/system recommendation questions, so this question is almost certain to be closed. If you can get 20 reputation, you're welcome to join us in [chat] where it's perfectly OK to talk about that sort of thing.

Comment: No problem, we were all new once. :)